# Avoid scroll top on click button

Tags: jquery

I am creating sections where I have to hide and show the divs. Everything is working fine except, when I click on the button to continue to next section it scrolls the to top, and then I have to scroll down again to see the section. I have searched for this solution I found that many people saying to use e.preventDefault(), but dint work for me. Againg I saw this  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false; it also dint worked.
Below is the button and the js code for which I want to scroll.

```
<a href="#order"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn_order">ORDER NOW</button></a>

$('.btn_order a').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 5000);
            return false;
})
```

This button I am using to scroll down to the section where questions are placed.

Below is the button which shows the next section and hides the previous section

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default abc_right  next_btn">Continue</button>
```

JS:

```
$('.abc_right').bind('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('.amount_wrap input:text').val().length == 0){
        setNotification('error', "Please enter min stamp amount Rs 100!");
    }
    else{
        $('.select_doc').show();
        $('.estamp_wrap').hide();
    }
})
```

When I click on this button it scrolls up and I dont want the div to scroll up. Any help would be appreciated. I not able to find what's getting conflicted.

Comment: this seems to be contradictory script is for $('.btn_order a') but in your html .btn_order is inside anchor. can you check this? I guess order should be reversed

Comment: Yeah so how I should write  like this $(' a .btn_order) ?

Comment: .btn_order a it should be something like a .btn_order and use event.preventDefault()

Comment: No the button which I click still scrolls up

Comment: You will need to `prevenDefault()` on the onclick event for the wrapping anchor element as well, because the `href=#` causes such behaviour.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8v0a5t91/1/ try this